# How to align html divs in rows and columns like a matrix

Tags: css

I'm trying to align 6 divs in this way:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

but I don't know how to do it, all divs are dimensioned by percentage

```
#folders {
background: #1abc9c;
height: 95%;
width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: Why are they set as percentages? Or more importantly, why those percentages?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if that was helpful

Answer (score 2):

```css
.folders{
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.folder {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}
```

```html
<div class="folders">
  <div class="folder">1</div>
  <div class="folder">2</div>
  <div class="folder">3</div>
  <div class="folder">4</div>
  <div class="folder">5</div>
  <div class="folder">6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two problems:

1. Your percentages don't really make any sense based on what you describe. They should be 1/3 width and 1/2 height.
2. You are likely dealing with an old CSS problem, that width and height is based on the last non-`static` `position`ed element, meaning the sizes from such tend to not appear right.

Based on that, here is a proper way to do this:

```css
.div-wrapper
{
  position: relative;
}

.div-wrapper div {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

The percentages are corrected, and a parent element that is non-`static` will ensure those percentages reflect its size. `relative` is essentially just a time-honored CSS hack for this issue.

`float` essentially instructs the browser to attempt to draw them all on the same line, but flow onto the next if it cannot. Just like text with word wrap. `left` and the alternative, `right`, specify the ordering of the elements the float is applied to.

Using `box-sizing: border-box;` will also allow you to add a border to the divs, without having to do any `calc` on the width/height, and have the sizes still work properly.

Comment: it was an example... my measures are: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkd1cuwwxbjxoko/example.png?dl=0